# Writing a regular expression with special characters

Tags: php, regex

As preface, I am new to (and really bad at) writing regular expressions.

I am trying to use a regular expression in the PHP function [`preg_split`](https://www.php.net/preg_split), and am looking to delineate by

```
*
**
`
```

I'm having trouble because these characters are commands. How can I write a regular expression to do this?

Comment: Quote them with `\\`.

Comment: You can also use [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote) to automatically escape these characters for you - this also helps ensure that there is no mixup, because backslashes are actually processed twice (once by PHP, once by PCRE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [`PCRE`](http://www.pcre.org/) and other so-called compatible flavors, you must escape these outside [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

```
. ^ $ * + ? () [ { \ |
```

The **backtick** has no special meaning, so you don't need to escape it.

```
preg_split('/\*{1,2}|`/', $text);
```

See [`Demo`](https://eval.in/72861)

**Note**: For future reference, you may want to look into using [`preg_quote()`](https://www.php.net/preg_quote)

> preg_quote() takes str and puts a backslash in front of every character that is part of the regular expression syntax. This is useful if you have a run-time string that you need to match in some text and the string may contain special regex characters.

Answer (score -1):

```
preg_split("(?:\*{1,2}|\`)", $string);
```